# App crashing with +[NSDecimalNumber gad_negativeOne]: issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, admob, google-ad-manager

My app was working before well, then i added `admob framework` and now its crashing .

Please check the crash logs,

[image]

i have tried in Google but there is no result regarding this crash.

If i commented the contents inside `viewDidAppear()` then app is working(not loading app part). But if am trying to load "admob" then its crashing.

---

#### Code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if([Connectivity hasConnectivity]){
        // [self loadAds];
        NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 15.0 target: self
                                                          selector: @selector(callAfterSixtySecond:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    }
}
-(void) callAfterSixtySecond:(NSTimer*) t
{
    
    if([GMMConnectivity hasConnectivity]){
        
        [self.adBanner removeFromSuperview];
        [self loadAdmob];
    }
}

-(void)loadAdmob{
    
    CGPoint origin;
    if(IS_RETINA){
        if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height >500){
            //        NSLog(@"5");
            origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                                 568-
                                 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height);
        }else{
            //        NSLog(@"4");
            
            origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                                 (480)-
                                 CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height);
        }
    }else{
        //        NSLog(@"3");
        
        origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             (460)-
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height);
        
    }
    // Use predefined GADAdSize constants to define the GADBannerView.
    self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
                                                   origin:origin]
    ;
    
    // Note: Edit SampleConstants.h to provide a definition for kSampleAdUnitID
    // before compiling.
    self.adBanner.adUnitID = MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID;
    self.adBanner.delegate = self;
    [self.adBanner setRootViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];
    self.adBanner.center =
    CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.adBanner.center.y);
    [self.adBanner loadRequest:[self createRequest]];
    [self.view addSubview:adBanner_];
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to add "**-ObjC**" to **Other Linker Flags** of  **Build Settings** tab.
Good luck!

Comment: but i already did that ..please check my latest screen shots in question.

Comment: i have added  -Objc  instead of -ObjC

Comment: Hi Pei even by adding -ObjC I am getting same exception,please suggest me any different solution.(I am following all steps suggested at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#ios)

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
[GADStaticDictionary decrementNumberForKey: shouldNotifyDelegate:];
```

The delegate is probably of type `NSDecimalNumber`, and this class **doesn't implement a method called** `gad_negativeOne`.

From the crash log, the problem is this. Now you should check your classes and understand what `delegate` are you setting, and where the `gad_negativeOne` method is.

Also because, a **method with a prefix** like this `gad_` should be a **private method**.

Comment: Actually, prefixing is best practice for **category methods**. NSDecimalNumber already has two convenience methods for `one` and `zero`. It looks to me like they simply extended NSDecimalNumber with a another method to return a number with `-1`.

Comment: and for private methods, because if you extend a class and implement some new methods, you could override a method which you don't see in the public interface.

Comment: but when i tried every google ad sdk,its crashing with same error